# Node.js traverse HTML files and extract angular elements that needs translating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I have a set of html and js files that needs translating. Instead of traditionally copying pasting each keys to a json file, I was wondering if there was a way to do this faster by building a Node JS script. I have a JS script currently which traverses recursively on the directory. And, able to read the current file which is being traversed. But, I want to only extract angular elements that needs to be translated.
 `{{"Welcome" | translate}}` <-- HTML 
 `$scope.word = {$translate.instant('Export Attendance');` <-- JS Controller


Basically, these are the patterns I want my program to look out for, and only capture the strings into another seperate JSON file.

Currently I have a program that is below.

get_translations.js

```
var read = require('recursive-readdir-sync');
var fs = require('fs');


try {
 root = read('./files/that/has/html/and/js');

} catch (err) {
if (err) {
    console.log("File does not exist");
} else {
    throw err;
}
}

for (var a=0; a<root.length; a++) {
console.log(root[a]);
fs.readFile(root[a], 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
   if (err) {
       throw err;
   } else {
       console.log(data); //need help here.. (noob)
   }
});
}
```

I'd like to avoid JQuery as much as possible. Any light shed on the matter will be greatly apprecieated.

Thanks.
Noob Javascript